# What are the conditions on $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ so that $A$ will not be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix in which all the rows are equal:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & \dots & a_{n} \\
    a_{1} & a_{2} & \dots & a_{n} \\
    \vdots  &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
    a_{1} & a_{2} & \dots & a_{n} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

what are the conditions on $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ so that $A$ will **not** be diagonalizable?

Comment: My guess is that $A$ is not diagonalizable if and only if $u=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ is not zero and orthogonal to $v=(1,\cdots,1)$. To see this, check that $A^2=\langle u,v\rangle A$.

Comment: Let $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$ and let the first row of $A$ be $a^T$. Over a general field, $A$ is non-diagonalisable if and only if $a^Te=0$ but $a^Ta\ne0$.

Comment: @user1551: Suppose $A$ is a $p\times p$ matrix over a field of characteristic $p$ in which all entries are equal to $1$. The matrix is not diagonalizable in that case, yet we have $a=e$, so your condition is not met.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right. I have mistakenly assumed that $a$ and $e$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @user1551: Your test works in characteristic zero; but it may fail in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 5):

If $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(0,\ldots,0)$, then $A$ is the zero matrix, which is diagonal and hence diagonalizable.

Assume then that $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\neq 0$. Then the matrix has rank $1$, so the nullspace has rank $n-1$; that means that the eigenvalue $0$ has at least $n-1$ linearly independent eigenvalues. At this point, it is just a question of the remaining eigenvalue.

Note that since every row has the same sum, the vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. If $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\neq 0$, then this eigenvector is linearly independent from those corresponding to $0$, giving you $n$ distinct linearly independent eigenvectors, and $A$ is diagonalizable.

Note as well that the eigenvalues add up to the trace, $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. That means that in addition to the eigenvalue $0$ with mulitiplicity $n-1$, the only other eigenvalue is in fact $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. Thus, if $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$, then $A$ has eigenvalue $0$ with algebraic multiplicity $n$, but geometric multiplicity $n-1$, so $A$ is *not* diagonalizable.

In summary, $A$ is not diagonalizable if and only if $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\neq (0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $a_1+\cdots+a_n =0$.

Comment: I was gonna say that. You don't need the fact that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues:  For every $x$ there exists $c$ with $Ax=c\Bbb 1$, where $\Bbb 1=(1,1,\dots,1)^T$. This shows that if $Ax=\lambda x$ and $\lambda\ne0$ then $x$ is a multiple of $\Bbb 1$.